# Excel VBA Copy range into table

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have been unable to figure out how to paste a range (specifically one row) into a data table using VBA.

Right now there is a range of data in a worksheet named "RawData". On another sheet there is a graph that starts at (1, 1) and goes to (100, 33). The variable ThisValue contains the name of the sheet containing the table. The variable x contains the row number of the range I am attempting to transfer.

I am currently using this code:

```
Sheets("RawData").Select
Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
Sheets(ThisValue).Select
NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The problem that I am facing is that it pastes the range of data directly below the table and not in the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But where would you like to copy to,  which row exactly?

Comment: To the first available (empty) row in the table.

Answer (score 3):

Tables should be addressed as ListObjects in VBA not as Ranges/Cells.

You should find what you require [here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp) in the section 'inserting rows and columns'.