# Copy Data From One Workbook Into Existing Table in Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to read another workbook and copy the contents, but when I try to paste into the existing Table - Excel hangs and freezes. If I copy the data into another sheet with no existing Table, then it works fine.

I am using this:

```
Dim sFound as String
Dim lRow as Long
Dim data_sheet As Worksheet
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim wb_data as Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

sFound =  Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\data*.csv)
If sFound <> "" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFound

End If
Set wb_data = ActiveWorkbook
Set data_sheet = Sheets("raw data")

lRow=data_sheet.Cells(data_sheet.Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row
data_sheet.Range("A10:V" & lRow).Copy

wb.Sheets("Data").Range("Data[Code]").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wb_data.Close
```

Any assistance in why the paste is causing the hang up in the table would be greatly appreciated.

2018-09-21 Update
I managed to fix the freezing and hanging through a combination of Marucciboy2's post and my own research. I stored the entire raw data set I was copying into a variant variable. Then, I resized the new table I was copying to to be the same length as the raw data. Then I just set that entire data range value the same as the variant variable. I will update this with the code.

I am still having one issue with is figuring out how to copy one particular column or certain range of columns of one table into another table. I can resize the new table just fine. I just don't know how to set one column into a variant variable or if I need to do something else. Then, I don't know how to set the new table column to that variant variable. Again, will have to post code tomorrow.

Comment: Do you want to append the data or overwrite the existing table?

Comment: You're missing an endquote for the line you set `sFound` in

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437455/excel-vba-copy-range-into-table

Comment: In the beginning of the code I clear all the data from the table except the header and 1 row exists after the header with no data. So my goal is just to get it to paste into the fresh table which always Starts at A2, but I was hoping to use the Table object.                                                        Sorry I am typing on mobile. The code seems to run now, but it takes a long time. Still pasting into a non table is faster for some reason. I can provide more code if needed. Thanks for the link Marucciboy2. I will try to utilize that.

Comment: All the tables and pivots are generated from the imported data and the reference tables existing within the Workbook. I will post shortly. But it really takes a while and it seems to hang for a while. One thing I was missing was initializing the lrow variable. Thank you for the replied so far and further help would be greatly appreciated.